# How to add an image instead of text 'My Cart' in top link - Magento

Tags: php, html, css, zend-framework, magento

This is probably some thing very simple and I tried a couple of things and various posts but none seem to get it working.

I would like to have a shopping basket image instead of 'My Cart' text in top links. How do I get this image to appear as the link instead of the text?

This image is in mytheme/images. I have tried editing Checkout/Block/Links.php, edited styles.css by putting

```
.top-link-cart { background url(HD/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/devsite/skin/frontend/default/mytheme/images/cart.png)left center no-repeat; }
```

But can't seem to get the image instead of the text. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had the following errors in your CSS:

- Missing colon (:) after background
- Missing space between URL and keyword left
- Your image link was absolute and not relative (not an error but will make putting the site live easier)

Here is what your code should be:

```
.top-link-cart { background url('../images/cart.png') left center no-repeat; }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This did work. Just with the colon between background n url. Thanks a lot. Do u think you can tell me how to include an image just next to the top category menu names?

Comment: I'm not sure which categories you are referring to; do you have a link? I would advise just looking for a class you can hook onto

Comment: How would I add a smallcart icon next to the My Cart text?

Answer (score 2):

use `background:url('image link')` no-repeat and define then define your `width` and `height` also make sure you define `text-indent: -9999px` or a higher number this way you will be left with image and your text would be out of the screen.

Here are tons of other ways which you can use for Css Image Replacement :
http://css-tricks.com/css-image-replacement/

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that the URL for the image is not correct, it looks to me as though you are trying to display it using the location on disk. It actually needs to be the location, relevant to the root of your website.

For instance, if the website root is `HD/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/` then you need to make the URL `/devsite/skin/frontend/default/ats_the‌​me/images/cart.png`.

Alternatively, you can make it relative to your css file. So if your css file is in `HD/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/devsite/skin/frontend/default/ats_the‌​me/css/` you can change the url to `../images/cart.png`

Comment: I have tried both the combinations, still they dont seem to work.

Comment: It just worked. I am sorry earlier I was missing a colon between background n url. I have written `../images/cart.png` and it works. Do you think you know how to add an image next to the top category's menu names?

Answer (score 0):

Add a colon after `background:`?

Comment: This is my code, is it wrong? `.top-link-cart { margin-left:40px; background:url(HD/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/devsite/skin/frontend/default/ats_theme/images/cart.png) no-repeat; width:10px; height:10px; text-indent: -9999px;} `

Comment: Your code appears correct. What problems are you experiencing now? The missing colon was the first thing I saw that looked like it'd be causing issues. Do you see the image?

Comment: No i do not see any image. I still just see my cart text. I have added this line in my css file and have checked in my folder, even the image exists n is in the right place. I don't know why the image still doesn't come at all

Comment: 1. Try inspecting that element with Firebug.
2. Hover over the background property URL and make sure that the image appears.
3. If it doesn't - there is a problem with your path.
4. If it does - try specifying the X and Y position of the image such as `background:url(HD/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/devsite/skin/frontend/default/ats_the‌​me/images/cart.png) 0 0 no-repeat;`
5. Modify the X and Y values until you see the image, then save those values in your CSS file (Firebug doesn't edit files, it only modifies them so you can debug).